# Git error on Cygwin, never seen before, fresh install

Tags: vim, cygwin

I just reformatted my OS-HDD today, did a clean sweep of all software, fresh installs (I love when I get to do that!).

On my re-install of Cygwin, everything is fine, except for the following issue:

**Cygwin-Git issue** *(pre: git init, git add *)*

```
    Justin@DESKTOP-Q66GK39 /cygdrive/c/ti/lib/jmrTemp
    $ git commit
    Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim:
    line  100:
    E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
    line  101:
    E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
    line  102:
    E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
    line  114:
    E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
    Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

**Error Code Source**

```
#vim80/defaults.vim:99-102
    autocmd BufReadPost *
      \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
      \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
      \ endif

#vim80/defaults.vim:112-114
    if !exists(":DiffOrig")
      command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
              \ | wincmd p | diffthis
```

**Questions**

1. Where does these errors come from?
2. How to correct or remove these errors?

Comment: `:help E10` suggests that mabe command-line continuations are disabled. Check `:set cpoptions?` to see whether it contains the `C` flag. If so, see where it was added and remove it. Does that help?

Comment: here's my readout: "cpoptions=aAbBcCdDeEfFgHiIjJkKlLmMnoOpPqrRsStuvwWxXyZ$!%*-+<>;"

Comment: how do I modify cpoptions? I was trying to remove 'C', but I am having the worst time in doing so!... :(

Comment: that `cpoptions` value is worrying. It looks like someone tried to set all possible flags. Most of those aren't even valid. `:verbose set cpoptions?` should tell you where this value was set (vimrc or plugin). My suggestion would be to read `:help 'cpoptions'`, decide what you need, and set only those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the multi-lines... duh :)!

Here is my working copy:

- [defaults.vim](http://justinreina.com/misc/17_03_26_GitProblem/defaults.vim)

**Solution 1**

```
autocmd BufReadPost * if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

**Solution 2**

```
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis | wincmd p | diffthis
endif
```

Embarassing I didn't try this earlier, sheesh. Posting here for others, if needed! :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this problem is to just modify the file in question to use the "standard" line-continuation method which is a `\` character at the **end** of the line to be continued (whereas this file is attempting to do the alternate way of a `\` at the **beginning** of lines 2+)

Example:

```
#vim80/defaults.vim:99-102
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
  \ endif
```

Should be changed to:

```
#vim80/defaults.vim:99-102
autocmd BufReadPost * \
  if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | \
    exe "normal! g`\"" | \
  endif
```

Comment: That "standard" location unfortunately isn't "standard" in Vim. In fact, it does not work at all.

Comment: The behavior and rationale are documented within vim under :help line-continuation

Comment: Yes, and it says: _Most programs work with a trailing backslash to indicate line continuation.  Using this in Vim would cause incompatibility with Vi._ So, it's **leading backslash**.